# Speed up DNSSEC keygen

Tags: ubuntu, dnssec

I'm rebuilding some DNS boxes and for the life of me I can't remember what I installed that drastically speeds up the dnssec-keygen process.

Would anyone know what this might have been or a way I could find out on the current box?

```
dnssec-keygen -a RSASHA256 -b 2048 -n ZONE ......
dnssec-keygen -f KSK -a RSASHA256 -b 4096 -n ZONE .....

dnssec-signzone -A -3 $(head -c 1000 /dev/random | sha1sum | cut -b 1-16) -N INCREMENT -o ..... -t .....
```

Answer (score 1):

It'd be helpful if you showed us *exactly* what you're doing.  But taking a guess, you're using `-r /dev/random` for your entropy, which blocks when the pool is empty, and that tends to happen very quickly on servers without KVM.  You can attach a [hardware entropy source](http://onerng.info/), you can use `/dev/urandom`, or you can generate the keys on a desktop machine (which has you there to provide a much deeper entropy pool) then copy them across.

Comment: updated. I know there was something I had to install from apt-get that increased the speed but I can't remember what I installed.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following to speed up the process.

```
apt-get install ldnsutils haveged
```

Answer (score 0):

@**Tsukasa**: I know that this should be a comment, but I do not have 50 reputation, so I cannot comment. Anyway, your proposed solution is the recommended solution and is the solution that I have used many times both on Fedora 27 and 29, for which the code needs to be:

```
yum install haveged
systemctl restart haveged
systemctl enable haveged
```

The above will ensure that **haveged** is installed, running, and automatically started following any reboot of the system ...and, yes (for the odd pedant wanting to mark me down for having the temerity to reference a different distro), I am aware that the OP's distro is Ubuntu; but the point is that **haveged** is the solution and that it can additionally be used on Fedora / RHEL too, thereby helping other people with a like issue who might not be using Ubuntu.

Comment: `yum install rng-tools ; systemctl restart rngd ; systemctl enable rngd` is another viable (possibly better) alternative.